# Assigning value in python 2d list

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have previously worked in C, I am facing problem in assigning value in 2d list

```
graph = [[0]*3]*3
print(graph)
graph[0][1] = 3
print(graph)
```

Output

> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
> [[0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0]]

Expected output :

> [[0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Is there any way to assign values other than using numpy array as answered in
[Assigning values Python 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138313/assigning-values-python-2d-array)

Comment: Yes, but I still can't understand how is it different from graph = [[0]*3]*3

Answer (score 2):

you can use a for loop to do this simply

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append([0]*3)
```